# Rails 3 and Acl9: find all subjects for a given object/role

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3, arel, acl9

I'm using **rails3** with **acl9** for authorization. I'm trying to grok ARel and the rails way of querying.

I have a *User* that belongs to a *Company*, and the user has a given role (acl9 provides the plumbing) over the *Company*. How can I get all *Users* from a given *Company* that have a specific role? **I want to filter the results in the DB**, not filter them in the application.

I want something like this:

```
# 
# authorizable_id = 1 is the company's id
# 'collaborator' and '1' would be params for my scope
#
select * from users
inner join roles_users
on roles_users.user_id = users.id
inner join roles
on roles_users.role_id = roles.id
where roles.authorizable_type='Company'
and   roles.authorizable_id = 1
and   roles.name = 'collaborator';

#usage with scope
@collaborators = User.with_role_and_company('collaborator',current_user.company)
```

I know rails3 has a sql api, but I come from a Java/Grails place, and most of the ORMs I use have some ORM api (I suppose datamapper works like this, but I'm using plain rails3).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out:

```
 class << self
   def with_role_in_company(role, company)
      joins(:roles).
          where(:roles => {:authorizable_type => 'Company'}).
          where(:roles => {:authorizable_id => company.id}).
          where(:roles => {:name => role})
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

I also added this feature in [acl9](https://github.com/be9/acl9) 1.2, so now you can just do:

```
company.users :collaborator
```